# How to get an the id inserted using Oracle and Zend

Tags: php, sql, oracle, zend-framework

My problem is that, i dont know how to get the id of the first column just inserted with a sql query. I want to stock this id in a php var to use it later. I saw that in Oracle to get the data after an insert is `returning column into variable` but i dont know how to make a communication between this thing and the php Zend. The `toto` variable is always empty. Im using ZendFramework and Oracle.

What i tried to do :

```
public function createNewAssemblage($aQData)
{
    $toto = " ";
    // Recuperation du nouveau ID assemblage
    // Preparation de la requete pour l'insertion des données dans la table
    // assemblage
    $sQuery = "INSERT INTO assemblage (
        id_depot_publication, num_assemblage, orig_assemblage)
        VALUES (:0, :1, :2)
        returning ID_ASSEMBLAGE into :3";

    $valReturn = false;
    $mResult = $this
        ->executeQueries($sQuery,
            array($aQData['id_depot_publication'],
                $aQData['num_assemblage'], $aQData['orig_assemblage'],$toto
            ));
    $this->_logger->err("--------------------------------");
    $this->_logger->err("ID_ASSEMBLAGE");
    $this->_logger->err($toto);
    $this->_logger->err("--------------------------------");
    // Mise en session de l'identifiant session
    if ($mResult) {
        $this->commit();
        $sQuery = 'SELECT ASSEMBLAGE_ID_ASSEMBLAGE_SEQ.currval FROM dual';
        $this->executeQueries($sQuery);
        $aResultSet = $this->getOneResult();
        $_SESSION['saveIdAssemblage'] = $aResultSet;
        self::$staticIdAssemblage = $aResultSet;
        $valReturn = $aResultSet;
    }

    return $valReturn;
}
```

The result :

```
2019-11-07T15:23:25+01:00 ERR (3): --------------------------------
2019-11-07T15:23:25+01:00 ERR (3): ID_ASSEMBLAGE
2019-11-07T15:23:25+01:00 ERR (3):  
2019-11-07T15:23:25+01:00 ERR (3): --------------------------------
```

Answer (score 0):

On submission of the new record you could immediately query to find the max ID assuming that the IDs are auto incremented.  You could write it up as a single stored procedure that inserts and pulls the new ID as a return value.